# Why I cannot use Error() for type validator.FieldError

Tags: go, error-handling, interface

I am using go validator and everything is fine. I can use print everything from err but cannot use `Error()` or convert the `err` to `string`. Does anyone can help me with this?

It shows

```
err.Error undefined (type validator.FieldError has no field or method Error)
```

My code:

```
err = validate.Struct(myData)

if err != nil {

    for _, err := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(err.Namespace())
        fmt.Println(err.Field())
        fmt.Println(err.StructNamespace())
        fmt.Println(err.StructField())
        fmt.Println(err.Tag())
        fmt.Println(err.ActualTag())
        fmt.Println(err.Kind())
        fmt.Println(err.Type())
        err.Error()

    }

    return
}
```

Is there any way to use the interface `Error()`? Or convert the `err` to `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "outer" `err` is an `error` (which is returned by [`validate.Struct()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9#Validate.Struct)), it has an `Error()` method.

But the `err` loop variable is not. You type assert [`validator.ValidationErrors`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9#ValidationErrors) from the "outer" `err`, which is:

```
type ValidationErrors []FieldError
```

Where [`FieldError`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9#FieldError) is an interface type but it has no `Error()` method.

You may call and print the error string of the "outer" `err` variable, before or after (but not inside) the loop.

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    for _, err := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To avoid such confusion, use a different name for the loop variable, especially since it's not of type `error`. `fieldErr` or simply `fe` (as in field error) would be a good name.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. That is the code I copied from the Go Validator documentation and I did miss the type assertion part and I thought it has the same interface Error().